# Cannot connect to secure socket.io server : ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with existing application. My application runs on https://somedomain.com. Its using this code to connect to socket io server:

```
 var socket = io('https://localhost:3456/');
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.send('hi');

    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      // my msg
    });
  });
```

My socket.io server has this code to listen to incoming connections:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3456);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("dupa");
    socket.on('message', function() {});
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {});
});
```

dupa is never displayed on server side and in Chrome browser console I receive:

```
GET https://localhost:3456/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1412901063154-0 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

How can I get this possibly working?

Comment: console.log("dupa"); looks quite familiar to me :D

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar problem with socket.io : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72293404/4106209

Answer (score 3):

Change https to http

`var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");`

Answer (score -2):

Your socket server is not using SSL.

First, add the secure parameter to your client (maybe redundant with the https but SSL+socket.io does weird stuff sometimes):

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost', {secure: true});
```

Then, you need your socket to be secure too :

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('YOUR SSL KEY').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('YOUR SSL CRT').toString();
var ca = fs.readFileSync('YOUR SSL CA').toString();

var io = require('socket.io').listen(3456,{key:privateKey,cert:certificate,ca:ca});
```

Comment: hmm where would I find 'YOUR SSL KEY' etc.? The app I run is on windows on my IIS but is configured to be run https:somedomain.com and Identity is not verified (the https:// is crossed out in browser url line). I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: that would be somewhere in your files, I have no idea how IIS stores it. key, ca and cert are all files