# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Socket.io and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl

I’m working with the Node.js server and using the Socket.io to manage connections by Socket but I’m having a problem with the SSL certificate.
Lot of users can access the Node.js server normally, but others users doesn’t access and they receive this error:
[image: User error]

When I set my server I have this SSL options:

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/root/cert/key.key', 'utf8').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/root/cert/cert.crt', 'utf8').toString();
var ca = fs.readFileSync('/root/cert/ca.crt').toString();
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca };
var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);
```

Somebody knows how to resolve this error? The problem is only some users receive this error.

Comment: Hard to tell from this few details but find out what's common with the users who fail (i.e. same browser, same network...) and also check your site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for problems for specific clients.  More help from remote can maybe done if you publish the URL of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see, you are missing a listening port for you https server.

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(<port>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had so much trouble with `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` that I have to give you my solution

NodeJS server `16.15.0` with `"socket.io": "2.4.1"` (I assume it works with other NodeJS versions)

```js
    const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const io = require("socket.io")();

    const folder = path.join(__dirname, "ssl");
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(folder, "server_key.pem"), "utf8");
    const certificate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(folder, "server_cert.pem"), "utf8");

    const optSsl = {
      key: privateKey,
      cert: certificate,
      ca: [certificate],
      requestCert: false, // put true if you want a client certificate, tested and it works
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    };

    const server = require("https");
    const webServer = server.createServer(optSsl);

    webServer.listen(8025); // port number
    io.listen(webServer);

    io.on("connection", (client) => {
        /*...*/
    });

    /*...*/
```

Angular `10.2.7` with `"ngx-socket-io": "3.2.0"` (I assume it works also with other Angular versions)

```js
import { Socket, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

/*...*/

socket: Socket;
socketConfig: SocketIoConfig;

socketConfig = {
      url: "https://myserver:8025", 
      options: {},
    };

socket = new Socket(socketConfig);
socket.connect();
```

Answer (score -4):

Looks like your apache2 is not properly configured.
Check if you have your config file enabled:

```
a2ensite default-ssl
```

And then restart the server.

Comment: The question is about node, there isn't any apache2 in this question.  The node.js is the server.