# socket.io https ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: https, socket.io, cloudflare

So basically I've been trying to get https working with my socket.io

server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpsapp = express();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require("fs");
var server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt').toString(),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem').toString()
  }, httpsapp);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var io = io.listen(8080);
(A whole bunch of socket.on's and one that sends one per second (they did work without https))
```

Client code:

```
var socket = io('https://server.com:8080', {secure: true});
```

I'm being filled to the brim with ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR errors
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: The certs are ones from cloudflare

Comment: Do you found solution?

Comment: I have a same problem

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar problem with socket.io : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72293404/4106209